# Multidimensional sparse array (3-way tensor) in R

Tags: r, tensor

Using the `Matrix` package I can create a two-dimensional sparse matrix.

Can someone suggest a package that would allow me to create a multidimensional (specifically a 3-dimensional) sparse matrix (array, or technically a three-way tensor) in R?

Comment: I don't think I've ever come across a 3D "matrix" in linear algebra.  What's it for?

Comment: In R a matrix is only 2D. A 3D (or indeed nD) matrix is called an array.

Comment: ok, he said "matrix" when he should have said "array"... but does it really need to be closed?!

Comment: I didn't vote to close. Just mentionned it thinking it would help the OP find what (s)he's looking for (if you don't have the proper vocabulary it's not easy to navigate through help pages).

Comment: @duffymo: you could use an array for storing multidimensional data, or for tensor operations ...

Comment: I'd forgotten about third order tensors.  I can see generalized tensors for physics problems, but not so much for statistics.  And I'd be more likely to imagine a list of matricies that I'd iterate over than a 3D matrix.

Comment: @BenBolker - I'm ashamed of myself.  How could I have forgotten the Riemann curvature tensor so quickly?  It's third order.  Continuum mechanics and elasticity uses a fourth order tensor to relate stress to strain.  I've been away too long.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor

Comment: Tensor math is used extensively e.g. for nonnegative tensor factorization and has important applications in many fields, so it would definitely be good if R offered solid support for that, see e.g. http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470746661.html

Answer (score 14):

The `slam` package has a `simple_sparse_array` class: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/slam.pdf, although it only has support for indexing and coercion (if you wanted to do tensor operations, or elementwise arithmetic, without converting back to a regular dense array, you'd have to implement them yourself ...)

I found this by doing

```
library("sos")
findFn("{sparse array}")
```

Comment: The name of the package seems to be `slam` and not `abind` though.

Answer (score 4):

There's also the `tensorr` package, which looks promising in providing support for sparse tensors, and tensor decompositions like PARAFAC/CANDECOMP etc are also on the to-do list:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tensorr/README.html