# How to make a three-way matrix from a list of dgCMatrix, in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of class `dgCMatrix` matrices in R, I can't construct a three-way matrix that allows access any element in ordinary way.

I've tried:

```
> Mat_three <- c(M1, M2, M3, M4, M5)
> Mat_three[1,1,1]
```

```
Error in Mat_three[1, 1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of `M1` , `M2` etc?

Comment: @akrun, thanks for answer: all matrices has same dim 

`> dim(Mi)
[1] 5960 5960`

Comment: As a vector works with `Mat_three[[1]][1,1]` but if execute `> sum(Mat_three[[]][1,1])
Error in Mat_three[[]] : invalid subscript type 'symb`

Comment: You have to show a small reproducible example

Comment: yes please show a reproducible example and tell more precisely what you want to do.  Thanks!

Comment: Here, a reproducible example: I want to work with the 3th dimension, like sum, mean, plot, etc. This doesn´t work. `> library(Matrix) 
> M1<-Matrix(rep(1,4),nrow=2,ncol=2,sparse=T) 
> as(M1, "dgCMatrix") 
2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
        
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 1 1
> 
> #I've tried
> threeway<-c(M1, M1, M1, M1)
> 
> threeway[1,1,1]
Error in threeway[1, 1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
> 
> #this way works
> threeway[[1]][1,1]
[1] 1
> 
> #this doesn't works
> sum(threeway[[]][1,1])
Error in threeway[[]] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to reshape your data so instead of accessing the (b, c) element of matrix a with `Mat_three[[a]][b,c]`, you instead combine them into a three-dimensional matrix where you could access that element with `Mat_three[a,b,c]`.

You can't use the `dgCMatrix` class for this, because it only supports two dimensions. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13818490/3093387), it looks like an option for higher-dimension sparse objects would be the `simple_sparse_array` from the `slam` package:

```
library(slam)
arr <- as.simple_sparse_array(do.call(cbind, Mat_three))
dim(arr) <- c(dim(Mat_three[[1]]), length(Mat_three))
```

Now, you can grab the (b, c) location of element a in your list with `as.vector(arr[b,c,a])`. For instance:

```
as.vector(arr[2,1,3])
# [1] 2
```

If your goal was saving keystrokes when accessing your data, it's probably best to keep your data in its original format.

Data:

```
Mat_three <- replicate(5, Matrix(1:4, 2, 2, sparse=TRUE))
```